# How are these 2 year old raspberry canes alive?

Tags: raspberries

[image: Sprouting leaves on raspberry cane]

This is one of two floricanes on my everbearing raspberry plant that are 2 years old. That is, they grew about 2 years ago and are now in their 3rd calendar year.

From what I've read, the general expectancy is that these should have been dead by now, but as you can see, there is still life in them.

Is this unusual or did I read the wrong sources? Or is it impossible and am I remembering their age wrong (unlikely). Could it be because we've had a very mild winter? I'm in zone 8a.

Also, what now? I'm inclined to just let them be and see what's going to happen, for fun and science. But academically, what should I now do with them if my goal were to get as many raspberries as possible? Will they even bear fruit at all? And what if my priority was instead to have a large, good-looking garden plant?

Comment: Looks alive. Black raspberries and ( red, yellow) raspberries have different growing modes , what do you have?

Comment: Don't know the exact name, but it produces red (pinkish) berries that look like the stereotypical raspberries

Comment: @blacksmith37 forgot to at. Also, photo: https://www.instagram.com/p/CEwSItTHJa6